# Boxed pgfplots reference in the text

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make a reference to a pgfplots graph in the text. The reference should be surrounded by a small box. I have tried several things but it always looks ugly. How can I vertically align the legend image in the box? How can I  align the box to the baseline.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=red] coordinates {(1, 1) (2, 200)};
    \label{pgfplots:plot}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
Some text \fbox{\ref{pgfplots:plot}} some text\\[1cm]
Some text \protect\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}] \protect\node[rectangle, color=black, align=center, draw] (P) at (0,0) [draw] {\ref{pgfplots:plot}}; some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mmmhh, could also be an option. I have just thought about a black frame which makes the legend symbol looks more nicer in the surrounding text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a box, you may use `hyperref` as suggested by cmhughes in the comment. However, here a a workaround: Add a `vphantom` for height...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=red] coordinates {(1, 1) (2, 200)};
    \label{pgfplots:plot}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
Some text \ref{pgfplots:plot} some text\\[1cm]
Some text \protect\tikz[baseline={(P.base)}] \node[rectangle, color=black, draw,inner sep=1pt] (P) at (0,0) {\ref{pgfplots:plot}\vphantom{t}}; some text
\end{document}
```

[image]